# prevent buttons from being pressed simultaneously

Tags: ios, uibutton

This is a simple problem, but tricky to solve.

I have two buttons that perform the same function.

I've set different touch events for the buttons. Although this helps, it's still possible to press them simultaneously. On a slow connection, it will be even easier.

```
[vote1Btn addTarget:self action:@selector(voteUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[vote2Btn addTarget:self action:@selector(voteUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Comment: What is the functionality of this button, and why is it tied to a "slow connection"?

Comment: Sounds like you might be doing network access on the main thread - that's bad.

Comment: Why do you use touch down on the second button? If you use touch up inside on both, you should be fine.

Comment: I only segue to the next view once the request is finished. Is there a more kosher approach?

Comment: It sounds like your buttons trigger a network request and while performing the request you don't want the buttons to be tapped again. Why don't you disable the buttons until the request completes to avoid duplicate requests?

Answer (score 25):

Set the `exclusiveTouch` property of both buttons to YES.

If that isn't enough, have each button call the shared application object's `beginIgnoringInteractionEvents` when its operation starts and call `endIgnoringInteractionEvents` when its operation ends.

Comment: If I could vote this answer up more I would - what a time saver!

Comment: Works like a charm in iOS10!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(UIView* v in self.view.subviews)
{
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton* btn = (UIButton*)v;
        [yourButton setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    }
}
```

this will work!